# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 10

Tags: php

When I click the SUBMIT button on the page with the form, I get the message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING...on line 10". I am new to PHP and can't figure out why it is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$to="me@my.com";
$subject="Bits";
$message=
"Customer name: ". $_POST ['name']. "\r\n".
"Email:         ". $_POST ['email']. "\r\n". "\r\n".
"Ordered Bits:  ". $_POST [''] . "\r\n" .

$from="$_POST ['email'];
$headers = "From: $from". "\r\n";
$headers = "Bcc: me2@my.com" . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Now that I've added the [tag:php] tag, the syntax highlighting should show you exactly what the problem is. This is why we recommend not using Notepad to develop unless you like constantly hunting for tiny errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
$to      = "me@my.com";
$subject = "Bits";
$message = "Customer name: ". $_POST ['name']. "\r\n" .
           "Email:         ". $_POST ['email']. "\r\n" . "\r\n".
           "Ordered Bits:  ". $_POST [''] . "\r\n" .

$from     = $_POST['email'];
$headers  = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: me2@my.com" . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Notice this line:

```
$from = $_POST ['email'];
```

I removed an extra double quote.

Comment: you missed concatenation operator should be `$headers .= "Bcc: me2@my.com" . "\r\n";`

Comment: Wasn't looking for more mistakes in his code :)

Comment: its good to correct that also. Otherwise he would have asked another question :)

Comment: Indeed, he might have. I corrected it.